# Any way to change Skype profile picture on-line?

Tags: skype-for-web

There are [many](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA3571/how-do-i-add-or-change-my-profile-picture-in-skype-for-windows-desktop) [different](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/change-photo-skype-30318.html) [guides](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Your-Picture-in-Skype) on how to change my own profile picture using Skype desktop client. But, is there any way to do this on-line, directly from Skype website? I don't see anything around such option, when digging [through my profile](https://secure.skype.com/portal/profile).

I'm not using Skype anymore. I have uninstalled it and forgot it long time ago. However, I found out, that my current profile picture is incorrect (showing to much privacy) and I want to change it. But, somehow I don't find the idea, of installing desktop (or mobile) client only to change my profile picture, too nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Try the usual way, login to the web chat:
https://web.skype.com/en/?intcmp=accountweb-_-uktrybeta (if this URL doesn't work, try your normal way to initiate a chat on skype-web)

and click on your profile picture in the left top corner of the screen. In the newly opened page, at the centre, click on your profile picture, which takes you to browse a picture on your desktop.

Answer (score 2):

**It is not possible**. [There is a discussion about this](http://community.skype.com/t5/Security-Privacy-Trust-and/change-profile-picture-in-web-interface/td-p/1591245) on the official Skype forums.